# How do I use PutMappingRequest with the Elasticsearch 8 Java API Client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, full-text-search, date-range

I am able to find an object with a datetime range corresponding to `2022-07-27` when sending the following HTTP requests from Postman to an Elasticsearch 8.3.2 server.

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/commit
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "dateTimeRange": {
                "type": "date_range",
                "format": "uuuu-MM-dd[['T'][ ]HH:mm[:ss[.[SSS][SS][S]][,[SSS][SS][S]]]][XXXXX][XXXX][X]"
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/commit/_doc/commit20220727?refresh
{
    "dateTimeRange": {
        "gte": "2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z", 
        "lte": "2022-07-27T23:59:59.999Z"
    }
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/commit/_doc/commit20220728?refresh
{
    "dateTimeRange": {
        "gte": "2022-07-28T00:00:00.000Z", 
        "lte": "2022-07-28T23:59:59.999Z"
    }
}

POST http://localhost:9200/commit/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "range" : {
            "dateTimeRange" : { 
                "gte": "2022-07-27T12:12:12.999Z",
                "lte": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, I am unable to use the Elasticsearch Java API Client and the query `datetime:[2022-07-27T12\\:12\\:12.121Z TO *]` to find an object with a date range corresponding to `2022-07-27`.

In ElasticsearchIndexerAndQuerierTest.java, the code on line 158 under comment `Attempt to search for commits with specific dateTime ranges` yields the assertion error `expected:<2> but was:<0>`.

How do I resolve this assertion error?

---

ElasticsearchIndexerAndQuerierTest.java

```
package Com.TSL.ElasticsearchIndexerAndQuerier;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.mapping.SourceField;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.DeleteRequest;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.DeleteResponse;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.IndexRequest;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.IndexResponse;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchRequest;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchResponse;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.search.Hit;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.CreateIndexRequest;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.CreateIndexResponse;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.DeleteIndexRequest;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.DeleteIndexResponse;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.PutMappingRequest;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.PutMappingResponse;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.RefreshResponse;
import co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpMapper;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.ElasticsearchTransport;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport;

public class ElasticsearchIndexerAndQuerierTest {

@Test
public void testElasticsearchIndexerAndQuerier() throws IOException {

    // Create a credentials provider.
    final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic", "password"));
    
    // Create a REST client.
    RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200));
    HttpClientConfigCallback httpClientConfigCallback = new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
        @Override
        public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
            return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
        }
    };
    restClientBuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientConfigCallback);
    RestClient restClient = restClientBuilder.build();

    ElasticsearchTransport elasticsearchTransport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

    ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(elasticsearchTransport);
    
    try {
    
        // Create index commit.
        CreateIndexRequest.Builder createIndexRequestBuilder = new CreateIndexRequest.Builder();
        createIndexRequestBuilder.index("commit");
        CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = createIndexRequestBuilder.build();
        CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = client.indices().create(createIndexRequest);
        System.out.println(createIndexResponse);
        
        // Store and index commit-dateTime strings as dates and commit-dangeTimeRange strings as date ranges.
        SourceField.Builder sourceFieldBuilder = new SourceField.Builder();
        String mappings =
            "{\n" +
            "    \"mappings\": {\n" +
            "        \"properties\": {\n" +
            "            \"id\": {\n" +
            "                \"type\": \"text\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            \"name\": {\n" +
            "                \"type\": \"text\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            \"dateTimeRange\": {\n" +
            "                \"type\": \"date_range\"\n" +
            "                \"format\": \"uuuu-MM-dd[['T'][ ]HH:mm[:ss[.[SSS][SS][S]][,[SSS][SS][S]]]][XXXXX][XXXX][X]\"\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";
        sourceFieldBuilder.includes(mappings);
        SourceField sourceField = sourceFieldBuilder.build();
        PutMappingRequest.Builder putMappingRequestBuilder = new PutMappingRequest.Builder();
        putMappingRequestBuilder.index("commit");
        putMappingRequestBuilder.source(sourceField);
        PutMappingRequest putMappingRequest = putMappingRequestBuilder.build();
        PutMappingResponse putMappingResponse = client.indices().putMapping(putMappingRequest);
        System.out.println(putMappingResponse);
        
        // Index a commit.
        IndexRequest.Builder<Commit> indexRequestBuilder = new IndexRequest.Builder<>();
        indexRequestBuilder.index("commit");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode dateTimeRange = objectMapper.readValue("{\"gte\":\"2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z\",\"lte\":\"2022-07-27T23:59:59.999Z\"}", JsonNode.class);
        Commit commit = new Commit("commit20220727", "Commit 2022-07-27", dateTimeRange);
        indexRequestBuilder.id(commit.getId());
        indexRequestBuilder.document(commit);
        IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(indexRequestBuilder.build());
        System.out.println(indexResponse);
        
        // Index a commit.
        indexRequestBuilder = new IndexRequest.Builder<>();
        indexRequestBuilder.index("commit");
        dateTimeRange = objectMapper.readValue("{\"gte\":\"2022-07-28T00:00:00.000Z\",\"lte\":\"2022-07-28T23:59:59.999Z\"}", JsonNode.class);
        commit = new Commit("commit20220728", "Commit 2022-07-28", dateTimeRange);
        indexRequestBuilder.id(commit.getId());
        indexRequestBuilder.document(commit);
        indexResponse = client.index(indexRequestBuilder.build());
        System.out.println(indexResponse);
        
        // Make sure searching can provide the commits.
        RefreshResponse refreshResponse = client.indices().refresh();
        System.out.println(refreshResponse);
        
        // Attempt to search for commits with specific dateTime ranges.        
        SearchRequest.Builder searchRequestBuilder = new SearchRequest.Builder();
        searchRequestBuilder.q("dateTimeRange:[2022-07-27T12:12:12.121Z TO *]");
        SearchRequest searchRequest = searchRequestBuilder.build();
        SearchResponse<Commit> searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, Commit.class);
        System.out.println(searchResponse);
        List<Hit<Commit>> hits = searchResponse.hits().hits();
        System.out.println("Hits");
        System.out.println("-----");
        for (Hit<Commit> hit : hits) {
            System.out.println(hit.source());
        }
        System.out.println("-----");
        assertEquals(2, hits.size());

    } finally {
        
        // Delete the first commit.
        DeleteRequest.Builder deleteRequestBuilder = new DeleteRequest.Builder();
        deleteRequestBuilder.index("commit");
        deleteRequestBuilder.id("commit20220727");
        DeleteRequest deleteRequest = deleteRequestBuilder.build();
        DeleteResponse deleteResponse = client.delete(deleteRequest);
        System.out.println(deleteResponse);
        
        // Delete the second commit.
        deleteRequestBuilder = new DeleteRequest.Builder();
        deleteRequestBuilder.index("commit");
        deleteRequestBuilder.id("commit20220728");
        deleteRequest = deleteRequestBuilder.build();
        deleteResponse = client.delete(deleteRequest);
        System.out.println(deleteResponse);
        
        // Delete index commit.
        DeleteIndexRequest.Builder deleteIndexRequestBuilder = new DeleteIndexRequest.Builder();
        deleteIndexRequestBuilder.index("commit");
        DeleteIndexRequest deleteIndexRequest = deleteIndexRequestBuilder.build();
        DeleteIndexResponse deleteIndexResponse = client.indices().delete(deleteIndexRequest);
        System.out.println(deleteIndexResponse);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PutMappingRequest.source sets the _source property of the mappings, which is not what I wanted. My goal was to set the entire mappings from JSON, which can be done using PutMappingRequest.withJson.

The section of code from `SourceField.Builder...` to `System.out.println(putMappingResponse);` should be replaced with the following.

```
        PutMappingRequest.Builder putMappingRequestBuilder = new PutMappingRequest.Builder();
        putMappingRequestBuilder.index("commit");
        String mappings =
            "{\n" +
            "    \"properties\": {\n" +
            "        \"id\": {\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"text\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"name\": {\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"text\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"dateTimeRange\": {\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"date_range\",\n" +
            "            \"format\": \"uuuu-MM-dd[['T'][ ]HH:mm[:ss[.[SSS][SS][S]][,[SSS][SS][S]]]][XXXXX][XXXX][X]\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";
        putMappingRequestBuilder.withJson(new StringReader(mappings));
        PutMappingRequest putMappingRequest = putMappingRequestBuilder.build();
        PutMappingResponse putMappingResponse = client.indices().putMapping(putMappingRequest);
        System.out.println(putMappingResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are my hero! I was stuck on ".source" because this was a way shown on
https://javadeveloperzone.com/elastic-search/elastic-search-put-mapping-example/
how it works (in Chapter 2.3 PUT Mapping XContentBuilder). I was false on that.

Well with your help i now build that:

```
XContentBuilder xcb = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
    xcb.startObject();
    xcb.startObject("properties");
    xcb.startObject("Rechnungsdatum");
    xcb.field("type", "date");
    xcb.endObject();
    xcb.endObject();
    xcb.endObject();
    String json = Strings.toString(xcb);
    System.out.println(json);
    PutMappingRequest pmr2 = new PutMappingRequest.Builder().index("rechnungen7").withJson(new StringReader(json)).build();
    PutMappingResponse pma2 = client.indices().putMapping(pmr2);
    System.out.println(pma2.toString());
```

Maybe this will help somebody one day =)

Thanks - Enomine